# Problem with Reinstalling Windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall, fdisk, lsass

I'm tring to reinstall Windows xp but I keep getting the message that "This CD contains a backup of the software originally installed on an HP Pavilion PC and can only be used with an HP Pavilion PC. If you are receiving this message on an HP Pavilion, please call HP Support". I have a Hp pavilion desktop and my sister had installed another hard drive in it.

I had recently gotten a virus that didn't allow me to access windows and said "lsass.exe application error". During the restoring process (I have the setup disks) it told me to use FDisk and I partitioned the master hard disk. After that I shut off the computer and turned it back on with the restore disk inside it.

As  I tried to reinstall windows, it gave me the message above("This CD contains a backup...") How do I reinstall windows? Please reply and help! As this is a fairly old computer I rather not spend that much money on it. Thanks!

Comment: Gotta "love" that technology that's architected to prevent things from functioning. I think you need to call/email HP support for this one.

Comment: Yeah you just got screwed by HP... Good luck with support. Either that or get another install media and just use the key off the back of your computer.

Comment: Download yourself the Windows XP ISO from wherever you'd like.  If you bought the computer from HP, there should be a (genuine) Windows XP serial number on the side, and as long as you have a legit serial number, you should be able to obtain the original install disc legally (regardless of how you choose to do so).